# How to mock variable in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

> Foo.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  let {val} = props;

  if (val) {
    return 'ReactComponentFail';
  } else {
    return 'ReactComponent';
  }
};
```

> Foo.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Foo from './Foo';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

let wrapper;

describe('foo test', () => {
  let props = { val: 0 }
  wrapper = shallow(<Foo {...props} />);

  test('component test', () => {
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('ReactComponent');
  });
});
```

How can i mock `props`? so, that i can get 100% code coverage any help would be highly appreciated.
I can't find anything on google regarding how to mock props.

Comment: You can't access local variable outside its scope, that's fundamental to JS. What's your real case? Foo is made-up and is efficiently `(props) => 'ReactComponent'`.

Comment: @ Estus Flask consider if i get val from props then how can i cover both if-else so i can have 100% coverage

Comment: Please, specify https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects your case because Foo doesn't. If you get it from props, you mock props, simple as that.

Comment: @EstusFlask can you now give more clarification or ref link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create mocked `props` and pass it to your SFC.

E.g.

`foo.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  let { val } = props;

  if (val) {
    return 'ReactComponentFail';
  } else {
    return 'ReactComponent';
  }
};
```

`foo.test.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Foo from './foo';

describe('foo test', () => {
  test('should return ReactComponent', () => {
    let props = { val: 0 };
    let wrapper = shallow(<Foo {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('ReactComponent');
  });
  test('should return ReactComponentFail', () => {
    let props = { val: 1 };
    let wrapper = shallow(<Foo {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('ReactComponentFail');
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62694921/foo.test.jsx (10.41s)
  foo test
    ✓ should return ReactComponent (6ms)
    ✓ should return ReactComponentFail

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 foo.jsx  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.845s, estimated 12s
```